# Junit reports for Hudson

Tags: junit

I am able to successfully run my JUnit test suite from the command line and now I want run these tests from Hudson.

However , for Hudson to generate the reports , it needs a results file (I think in xml format) .

How do I generate a results file from JUnit ? 
I am using the following command to run the tests :

```
java com.nvidia.tests.TestSuite1
```

Thanks in advance .

Parag.

Comment: Which build tool are you using? ant? maven? gradle?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ant, you can look at the [JUnit task for ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html). This is probably the easiest way. You can just add the task at the appropriate place in the script.

If you're using maven, look at the [surefire plugin for maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) which will automatically run the tests and create the reports in jenkins.

EDIT: If you're not using any build tool (which you should be), then just add the ant build script to jenkins, and you should get the reports automatically.

Comment: Hi Matthew , I am not using any build tool as I just compile the test suite with javac and then run with java.